# AccessSize importance in ASAN instrumented code

Tags: memory, memory-management, address-sanitizer

I have been recently dealing with the internals of *Address Sanitizer(ASAN)* and I came to know about the code instrumentation by ASAN.

> When instrumenting 1,2,4 byte accesses the instrumentation is:

```
ShadowAddr = (Addr >> 3) + Offset;
k = *ShadowAddr;
if (k != 0 && ((Addr & 7) + AccessSize > k))
    ReportAndCrash(Addr);
```

I couldn't understand what AccessSize in `line 3` does and why is it used there.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [AddressSanitizerAlgorithm wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm#mapping) each byte of shadow memory encodes the state of corresponding 7 bytes of user memory:

- 0 means that all 8 bytes are valid
- k=1..7 means that k bytes are valid
- (other values also mean something but we omit them for brevity)

Thus condition

```
if (k != 0 && ((Addr & 7) + AccessSize > k))
    ReportAndCrash(Addr);
```

means that if less than 8 bytes are valid (`k != 0`) and accessed memory range does not fit into valid bytes (`(Addr & 7) + AccessSize > k`) the access is incorrect and should be reported.